# Using query function with ' where Col1 or Col2 is not null'?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrays

```
=query({TOIM;IMTO},"SELECT * where Col1 is not null ORDER by Col11",0)
```

Where `TOIM`,`IMTO` are named ranges.
I want to rewrite the formula with two criteria (OR). In other words like this:

```
=query({TOIM;IMTO},"SELECT * where Col1 or Col3 is not null ORDER by Col11",0)
```

But that seems not the correct argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
*(following OP's comment)*

> So, how to say if either Col1 or Col2 is not null ?

```
" where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null "
```

---

**Original answer**

Depending on your locale, the formula behaves like

```
+---------+------+------+
| Formula | Col1 | Col2 |
+---------+------+------+
| ={1,2}  |    1 |    2 |
| ={1;2}  |    1 |      |
|         |    2 |      |
+---------+------+------+
```

So when you have `{TOIM;IMTO}` you can either have `Col1` and `Col2` OR JUST `Col1`.
In any case, there are no columns like `Col3` or `Col11`.

Please adjust your formula accordingly.

Comment: So, how to say if either Col1 or Col2 is not null ?

Comment: Have you tried the given solution? Did it work for you? If not we could try finding out why. If yes, please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Yes it worked. since my IMTO refers to a range of multiple columns, I can use any Col number that is included in IMTO range